# how to manage multiple cookies using javascript for same url

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am new in jquery, i want to manage several cookies in my page in jquery.

```
setcookie($cookie_name,$cookie_value,$time,"/");
```

like this php function i want

Comment: There are many, many examples of code to set and read cookies from Javascript. All over the web.

Comment: Give them separate names...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use this

```
    function createCookie(name, value, days) {
        if (days) {
            var date = new Date();
            date.setTime(date.getTime() + (days * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
            var expires = "; expires=" + date.toGMTString();
        }
        else var expires = "";
        document.cookie = name + "=" + value + expires + "; path=/";
    }
    function readCookie(name) {
        var nameEQ = name + "=";
        var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
        for (var i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
            var c = ca[i];
            while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') c = c.substring(1, c.length);
            if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) == 0) return c.substring(nameEQ.length, c.length);
        }
        return null;
    }
    function eraseCookie(name) {
        createCookie(name, "", -1);
    }

createCookie("mycookie_"+id,cookievalue,7);
```

Answer (score 1):

One small library that makes this really easy is `js-cookie`, [available here](https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie)

To set a cookie valid for 30 days:

```
var options = {expires: 30, path:'/'}
Cookies.set("cookie_name", cookie_value, options);
```

To read the cookie's value

```
 var cookie_value = Cookies.get("cookie_name");
```

To get all available cookies

```
var cookies = Cookies.get();
```

To delete a cookie:

```
Cookies.remove("cookie_name", {path:'/'});
```